# Is there a reason to use the Observer pattern over a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android

Recently, I have started working on an Android Project that stopped using Broadcast Receiver's in favor of "Listeners". Really, this implementation is using an observer pattern similar to [this article](http://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/) (in my case, there is even .aidl involved).

What I am failing to understand is why. I have been taught that composition is better than inheritance. To me, a broadcast receiver is composition. It is a native Android feature, that everyone Android developer should be familiar with. So why, is there any reason that I should drop my Broadcast Receivers in favor of an observer pattern? Is this just a product of bad design on my teams part?

Update:

I did find a comment stating that this is to follow [Single Responsiblity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), however I am not sure I follow as any class implementing a listener is bound to have other responsibilties (for instance, activities, who are managing the UI lifecycle).

Comment: Depending on the application I am with you, I am interested to see the answer as I would assume Broadcast Receivers would be your go to.

Comment: An observer could implement an interface. Then it is not inheritance.

Comment: My understanding is that broadcast receivers are for multi-process applications or crossing application domains (system-wide notifications). Broadcast receivers need to be locked down with permissions so they don't leak data to arbitrary apps.

When possible use the LocalBroadcastManager if they app has a single process.

I guess don't understand your definition of composition and inheritance in this context. A broadcast receiver is a listener so the distinction doesn't make sense.

Comment: @weston interesting point, have you tried this pattern yourself and if so have you found it a less error prone design than broadcast receivers?

Comment: I'd say the biggest risk here is hidden in the question. How are you having such a common pattern of observable background changes that support this debate? If that is the case, the activity should be thinned out and the business logic should be moved to a service.

Comment: It seems to me that a broadcast receiver would need to filter out irrelevant declarations (correct me if I'm wrong); a `Printer` class doesn't need to know that you have a wireless connection, or that you just got a phone call. An observer pattern solves this problem by being 'opt-in'; a class only subscribes to information it needs to know. EDIT: As @EricWoodruff says, Broadcast receivers appear to have the advantage of being ways to transmit data between running applications.

Comment: @EricWoodruff right, you can use Broadcast Receivers with LocalBroadcastManager, instead of calling sendBroadcast.

Comment: @Aarowaim Broadcast Receivers either receive global or local intents. I'm not sure though if the receivers have to filter out intents. I know you apply an intent filter, but whether or not the receiver has to manage the filtering is beyond me.

Comment: Isn't broadcast receiver also an implementation of observer pattern?

Answer (score 10):

Using `BroadcastReceiver`s allows to decouple one component from another. A sender doesn't know anything about receivers of his message. It just sends broadcasts and doesn't care if it was received and handled. The same concept has an event bus (for example [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)). But global `BroadcastReceiver`s have a small overhead because they are by their nature a cross-application facility. So if you need to send events only inside one application I would use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or the event bus that I've pointed previously.

In case of using listeners (observers) components become tightly coupled because sender has a reference to the receiver and know about it's nature (what interface a listener implements) and must check if the listener is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen 100 times that BroadcastReceiver uses the Observer design pattern, but still keenly disagree with this.
 First of all the definition of the Observer design pattern is :"The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their method". What object is observed in the BroadcastReceiver?
 The ctx.registerReceiver(receiver, filter) does not provide information about any object. Broadcast receiver in its idea  is not dedicated to notify number of classes about changes in any object- it is simply  listener of broadcast mechanism, but not only. In order to get notification about changes, you must register a receiver object with filters. You will get NO NOTIFICATION once you did not set a filters with receivers. So your receivers should be selected regarding intent's action in order to your onReceive(Intent,...) will be triggered. At least I see here the selector pattern. But not only it.  What really broadcast is doing? It propagates intents have been sent like a hub and selects registered receivers by filters of action.  Now see the definition of the mediator pattern(https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator). Is not the case? The broadcast mechanism implements skills enabling object interaction, where sender does know nothing about listener and listener says what it is to be listened regardless who has sent.Is it not mediator
Basically, BroadcastReceiver is indivisible part of the Broadcast mechanism of Android. Separation of BroadcastReceiver from the whole mechanism is simply not correct.From  It is like JMS message consumer is indivisible part of JMS. 
Intent, used in broadcast receiver is dedicated to transmit action and bundle of arguments(parameters, what else). It is used normally to transfer an action(!) with data.  Really, it is data object for command.
For comparison, let us consider the really well known case of Observer pattern in Android is ContentObserver. How it works:
 getContentResolver(). registerContentObserver( SOME_URI,true,         yourObserver); See, listener is attached to dedicated resource, not for general purpose listening. It is triggered once content changed (do you sent a notification about anything????) and notifies what is changed(Uri). Yes, this is THE OBSERVER really. It notifies about object changed and listener-observer sees what is changed in observed object. Is it the model of work of Broadcast????
In broadcast I see elements as least of mediator, selector and DTO.

Comment: Man I tried to properly format this answer but I gave up at the fifth period.